# Does Samuel L. Jackson exist in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, nick-fury

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Ned has a LEGO Death Star. Additionally, in *Captain America: Civil War*, Peter references *The Empire Strikes Back*. This means that Star Wars exists in the MCU.

One example of a Star Wars actor? Samuel L. Jackson, who plays Mace Windu. S.L.J also plays Nick Fury in the MCU. So who plays Mace Windu in the MCU? Does Nick Fury play them? Does Samuel L. Jackson exist in the MCU, and play Mace Windu? If so, do people mention how Nick Fury and Samuel L. Jackson look identical?

Comment: Supposedly MCU Samuel Jackson is another person than Nick Fury, or better yet, only the original trilogy exists in the MCU.

Comment: Just because Star Wars is mentioned, doesn't mean all the same actors exist.   Also, you have to question how literal the appearance of people in the movies actually matches the appearance in universe.  If you believe it does, then you have to explain why Bruce Banner and James Rhodes magically changed appearance.

Comment: Wow, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141370/3823) to @PaulD.Waite's link says exactly the same thing I did.

Comment: The [relatively-small London suburb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croydon) that I’m from [exists in the MCU](https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=iron_man_3_10965&p=29), so I wonder who plays me? I’m hoping for Simon Pegg.